# I'm having trouble changing a select list selected value

Tags: c#, jquery, html

I have a select list with an id of SelectedEmployee.  I have a on change event in jquery where I successfully get the value of the selected item:

```
        $("#SelectedEmployee").change(function () {
            selectedEmployee = $("#SelectedEmployee").val();
            $("div.myDropDownDiv select").val(selectedEmployee.toString());
            alert(selectedEmployee);          
            myCal.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');            
         });
```

My alert returns the value of the selected employee but the DOM still thinks the previous selection is the selected employee.  I have tried both the following within the change event with no luck.

```
$("div.myDropDownDiv select").val(selectedEmployee.toString());


$('#SelectedEmployee option[value=' + selectedEmployee + ']').prop('selected', true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example you gave

```
$("div.myDropDownDiv select").val(selectedEmployee.toString());
```

should work...

Here is a [Working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/LmdzLpat/)

Maybe you should check if `selectedEmployee.toString()` is returning the correct value.

Or even if the `select` is inside a `div` which has the class `myDropDownDiv`. 
Maybe, `myDropDownDiv` is an `id` instead of `class`